# Network connection delay after installing indicator-network

Tags: networking, wingpanel

Ok, so here's the thing,I installed wingpanel in Ubuntu 10.10, I removed the gnome-panels (yes, both). In the wingpanel itself there's no Network indicator, so I google it and in some forums, some guy wrote that you have to install `indicator-network`.

I did it, and it solved the network indicator in the wingpanel, But now every time I turn on my computer, the connection takes like 2 minutes or more to connect, when before installing this thing it did it immediately.

How can I solve this? Any help?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.